# Delegate the deletion of projects in sonar to users

Tags: sonarqube

Is it possible to delegate the deletion of projects in sonar to users ?
Knowing that the authentication of my sonar is managed by an ldap directory.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please be more explicit about your needs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SonarQube, project administrators have the right to delete the projects. So if you want to delegate deletion of projects to users, you must make sure that those users are granted Admin rights on the relevant projects.

As you are using an LDAP, you can do the following:

- At global level, create one group per project called (for instance) "admin_projectName" (replace "projectName" by each project name)
- In your LDAP, set the "admin_projectName" group on every user who should be project admin of a given project
- Configure the LDAP plugin to [synchronize the groups (called "Group Mapping")](https://redirect.sonarsource.com/plugins/ldap.html)

Comment: Hi,

thank you for your reply,

I want to give admin rights on a project automatically to a user, is it possible?